# Выравнивания объектов (CSS)

Tags: css3

Доброй ночи!
Я столкнулся лицом к лицу с такой проблемой, не могу выравнять кнопку по одной линии с counter'ами, если делаю кнопку ниже, то counter'ы непременно съезжают, как исправить ситуацию?

[image]

CSS:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');

* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}




.header {
  background-image: url('img/headbackground.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 9%;
}

p.inheader {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.875em;
  position: relative; 
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 1.6%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p.outcounter {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  position: relative; 
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}

p.incounter{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
  font-size: 1.313em;
  position: relative; 
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.3%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 3px;
}

p.outcounter2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  position: relative; 
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 12%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}

div.button {
  width: 278px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #2aaa3d;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px #008729 inset;
  transition: 0.3s;
  }

  div.button:hover {
  background: #008729;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px #007223 inset;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
p.inheader{font-size: 4vw;}
p.incounter{font-size: 1em;}
p.outcounter{font-size: 1em;}
p.outcounter2{font-size: 1em;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
.header{height: 300px;}
.logo{display:block; margin:10px auto 20px;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Snow</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="favicon" href="favicon.ico"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=450, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>

     <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
      <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
      <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->

    <div class="header">

        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
          <p class="inheader">Все заявки и поставщики в одном месте</p>
          <p class="outcounter">Заявок вчера:</p><p class="incounter">4</p><p class="incounter">1</p><p class="incounter">3</p>
          <p class="outcounter2">Заявок сегодня:</p><p class="incounter">4</p><p class="incounter">1</p><p class="incounter">3</p>
          <div class="button"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина в том, что кнопка лежит в том же диве, и при увеличении отступа кнопки уезжает ниже и остальное.

Возможный вариант решения: перенести кнопку в дополнительную колонку и там уже управлять отступом.

В этом случае HMTL часть кода будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
   <div class="header">

        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-lg-5">
          <p class="inheader">Все заявки и поставщики в одном месте</p>
          <p class="outcounter">Заявок вчера:</p><p class="incounter">4</p><p class="incounter">1</p><p class="incounter">3</p>
          <p class="outcounter2">Заявок сегодня:</p><p class="incounter">4</p><p class="incounter">1</p><p class="incounter">3</p>
        </div>


      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
             <div class="button"></div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Пример: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJgLQz